# In gremlin, how to find and sort all triads of connected vertices that a given vertex belongs to?

Tags: javascript, gremlin, amazon-neptune

I am making a social app where users can be friends.

For a given user `A`, I want to find all of the triads of users such that `A -isFriends-> B AND B -isFriends-> C AND C -isFriends-> A`.

My current approach is as follows:

```
g.V(A).repeat(__.out('isFriends')).times(3).path().by(id).toList()
```

and then outside of gremlin, I filter out all of the Path objects where the first object is not the same as the last object. I'd prefer to have gremlin do this filtering for me, but I'm unsure how to filter based on the output of `path()`.

I have tried `cyclicPath()`, but this simply returns a flat list of Vertex objects, which I do not understand. From this I would expect similar output to `path()` but with only the paths where the first and last vertices are the same included. Let me know if this expectation is incorrect.

I would also like to then sort these paths based on the results of a sub-traversal (how many mutual friends the three vertices have), but I am unsure how to run a traversal starting on the vertices included in the output of `path()`, without starting a new gremlin query.

I am using the javascript-gremlin driver (v3.4.4) and am making queries against AWS Neptune, where lambdas are not available.

Please let me know if my approach or understanding is off.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is a query to answer both your questions. It is **optimized** to run with only 2 hops:

```
g.V().hasLabel("A").as("A").both("isFriends").as("B").aggregate("friends")
.out("isFriends").as("C").where(within("friends"))
.project("triad","mutual")
  .by(select("A","B","C").by(label()))
  .by(select("B","C").select(values).unfold()
    .both("isFriends").where(within("friends"))
    .groupCount().by().unfold()
    .where(select(values).is(eq(2)))
    .select(keys).label().fold())
.order().by(select("mutual").count(local), desc)
```

**Some explanation:**

- Find A friends and store them as 'friends'.
- Then find their friends which are within 'friends' thus friends with A (use `out` this time to prevent duplication).
- Use project to make the result more verbose.
- Selecting A, B and C to get the triad.

Now come the fun part of finding the triad mutual friends:

- Start from B and C and find their friends which are also A friends.
- Group-Count those friends and filter only those which have count of 2 (friends with both B and C).
- Finally, sort the results by the count of mutual friends.

Instead of actual list of mutual friends, you can keep only their count by replacing last 2 lines:

```
    .select(keys).label().fold())
.order().by(select("mutual").count(local), desc)
```

with:

```
    .count())
.order().by(select("mutual"), desc)
```

Finally, if you want only the triads (still sorted) you can remove the project:

```
g.V().hasLabel("A").as("A").both("isFriends").as("B").aggregate("friends")
.out("isFriends").as("C").where(within("friends"))
.order().by(
    select("B","C").select(values).unfold()
    .both("isFriends").where(within("friends"))
    .groupCount().by().unfold().where(select(values).is(eq(2)))    
    .count(), desc)
.select("A","B","C").by(label()).select(values)
```

Comment: Wow, thank you very much. This is incredibly helpful. I have the first part working and I understand it. On the second part, I don't doubt that it works but I am confused by some of the steps. Could you post a modified query that only keeps the count without the actual list of mutual friends? That would help me to understand which steps are being done for which purpose in the second part. Definitely accepting once I understand, your time & knowledge is very much appreciated.

Comment: I added 2 more options as requested. The idea in finding the mutual friends is to traverse from both B and C to their friends, filter only those which are also friends with A as well, and find those duplicates ones (count=2) to get mutual friends of B and C. Hope it is more clear now.

Answer (score 1):

So I tried to create a sample graph for your issue:
[sample graph](https://gremlify.com/1q)

You are trying to find a simple cyclic path I think you can achieve that with:

```
g.V().hasLabel('A').as('a')
.both('isFriends').as('b')
.both('isFriends').as('c')
.where(both('isFriends').hasLabel('A'))
.select('a', 'b', 'c')
```

Note: that triads are symmetric so each of them will return twice.

Comment: Thank you for your solution, this works! Kfir's solution seems to be about twice as fast on my test data and includes the mutual friends part, though. Good point about the symmetry & duplicity. I'm definitely going to use gremlify in the future, such an awesome idea & tool.